# How to use HttpURLConnection with Response (Content-Type: text/html ) in android?

Tags: android, html, httpurlconnection

My qustion is about the code that should be written in Android using HttpURLConnection to get the response?

The Request and 2 Response as following:

Request
[Headers
Authorization: ******]

Response
[code: 302,
Headers
(Content-Type: text/html)]

Response
[code: 302,
Headers
(Content-Type: text/html)]

The code:

private void makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {

```
    String redirectUrl;

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "********");
        urlConnection.connect();

        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
                || urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                || urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP) {

            redirectUrl = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");

        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error redirect response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving", e);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/html");
```